# Expresión regular para permitir numeros negativos y positivos con punto decimal

Tags: jquery, regex

Busco en concreto solo permitir numeros positivos y negativos con punto decimal, pero la función que implementé me deja ingresar más de un punto y más de un símbolo negativo, cuando en realidad solo necesito **un solo punto** y **un solo signo negativo**

Adjunto mi codigo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="txt">

<script>
$('.txt').keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g,''); 
});
</script>
```

¿Qué le hace falta a mi expresión para que cumpla con lo que quiero?

Y ¿Dónde podría encontrar información completa y clara para aprender a utilizar y construir mis propias expresiones regulares?

Comment: Si solo quieres números... ¿no es más sencillo poner el input de tipo number? No veo la utilidad de esta función. De cualquier manera, puedes aprender expresiones regulares usando el curso gratuito de [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/#regular-expressions).

Comment: No, ocupo exactamente esa validación... el input number también permite dos "--" y la letra "e" cuando está en blanco.

Comment: Suponiendo que pongas la regex que corresponde, no se podría usar `replace` para ir corrigiendo lo que el usuario va ingresando, porque nunca podría comenzar a escribir, si comenzara a escribir un `-` ya se lo borrarías porque no es válido según los criterios que indicas. Osea, sería válido si es el único caracter, pero solo si continúa escribiendo cosas válidas, sino no.

Answer (score 1):

Reformulemos el problema así:

*En una cadena de caracteres, encontrar los caracteres que cumplan alguna de las siguientes condiciones, y eliminarlos:*

1. *El carácter no es un dígito ni un punto ni un signo menos:*

   `[^0-9\.-]`
2. *El carácter es un signo menos que no es el primer carácter de la cadena:*

   `(?<=.)-`
3. *El carácter es un punto después del cual existe otro punto en la cadena:*

   `\.(?=.*\.)`

Entonces, en el código de la pregunta, se debe utilizar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
[^0-9\.-]|(?<=.)-|\.(?=.*\.)
```

Cabe anotar que finalmente pueden quedar las siguientes cadenas, sin ningún dígito, que solo podrían validarse después de finalizar la entrada: **-** , **.** , **-.**

Por ejemplo, la cadena **-1-2x3.4.5** sería convertida a **-1234.5**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Probar en Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5ZA0GB/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$

- 0 o una vez.
un numero, 1 o más veces
un punto 0 o una vez
un numero 0 o más veces.  (Si no hay punto, solamente son numeros, entonces está bien.)
```

Puede aprender de Regex aquí https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp es en inglés pero hay un botón para traducir a español.

Además, puede probar su regex aquí https://regex101.com/

Comment: y cómo lo podría integrar a mi ejemplo?

Comment: Para quitar caracteres extrañas, no sé.  Para prohibir que se entre cáracteres prohibidas,  if (this.value.match("^\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$") != this.value) { alert ("Solamente numeros por favor."); }  Si son diferents, sabe que hay un problema.

Comment: como podría  cambiar ese expresión para que solo permita numeros enteros. negativos ó cero. ej: 0,12,4546,-1,-23,-34 pero que no valida -0 como true, y tampoco decimales.

Comment: Para numeros enteros, ^\d+$

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de validar un número en cada presión de teclas implica que no se pueda utilizar una sola expresión regular, porque en el proceso de escribir un número válido, el input a validar puede no ser válido. Ejemplo:

- Si el lenght del input es 1. Puede ser válido "-" o un número de 1 a 9.
- Si lenght del input es 2.

  - Puede ser válido un "-" seguido de un número de 0 a 9
  - Un número 1 a 9 seguido de un número de 0 a 9.
  - Un número de 0 a 9 seguido de "."

Así sucesivamente. Por ello no me parece conveniente validar en cada presión de teclas, en caso contrario hay que considerar cada situación intermedia de un número válido.